# .exe doesn't launch after making it with py2exe

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pyqt4, py2exe

So I have been working for 2 months on a project in python (it is the first time I'm using python). 
The project is basically:
- 1 main file, 
- 1 GUI file using PyQt4 
- and a few classes for the calculation functions.

Here is my setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
from glob import glob
import matplotlib

dataf = [
        (r'mpl-data', 
          [r'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-win32.egg\matplotlib\mpl-data\matplotlibrc']),
        (r'mpl-data\stylelib',
          glob(r'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-win32.egg\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\*.*')),
        (r'mpl-data\images',
          glob(r'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-win32.egg\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\*.*')),
        (r'mpl-data\fonts',
          glob(r'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\*.*')),
        (r'Qt\imageformats',
          glob(r'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\*.*')),
        (r'Resource',
          glob(r'C:\PythonWS\Lince5M\*.png')),
    ]

includes = ['sip', 'PyQt4.QtCore', 'PyQt4.Qt', 'PyQt4.QtGui', 'PyQt4.QtNetwork',]
pack = ['numpy.core', 'matplotlib.backends', 'matplotlib.axes', 'zmq', 'PyQt4.QtCore', 'PyQt4.Qt', 
    'PyQt4.QtGui', 'PyQt4.QtNetwork', 'CaptureImage', 'ClusterDetectionIterative', 'DisplayPanel', 
    'ImageProcessAvg', 'WriteOutputFiles',
    ]
excludes = ['_gtkagg', '_agg2', '_cairo', '_cocoaagg', '_fltkagg', '_gtk', '_gtkcairo', '_thread', 
        '_macosx',
        ]
#I admit not understand really much those excludes, that's why I don't put them in the setup

opts={
'py2exe': {
        'compressed': 2,
        'optimize': 2,
        'includes':includes,
        'packages':pack,
        #'excludes':excludes,
        'bundle_files': 1,
    }
}

win = [{
      'script': 'Application.py', 
      'icon_resourses': [(1,'icone\icone.png')]
   }
]

setup(
    version = "0.1",
    console=win,
    options=opts,
    data_files=dataf,
    )
```

My programs works fine when launched with Eclipse.

The making of the executable seems to be done fine too, except for the list of missing modules there is no error, and my .exe is created...

But when I start it nothing happens... I have been looking for a few days now and I really have no idea on what is wrong since nothing gives me a notice on the problem..

If it could be of any use, my project uses those imports:
PyQt4, os, decimal, time, numpy, sys, clr, matplotlib, cv2, and a dll we made in the company.

So here is my question:

1. Anyone ever got this kind of error?
2. Does any one know how **to get an output**, or anything that could tell me **where is the problem?**

Answer (score 0):

There should be a [.exe name].log file in the "dist" folder that py2exe created.
Try looking to see if that can glean some information on your problem.

Comment: At the beginning there wasnt but modifying some things now I have it, thanks.
I will check those errors in google and try to understand them.